# Display code auto-complete suggestions in BlueJ while typing

Tags: bluej, code-completion

I have been using BlueJ for over 5 years now.
But when it comes to Game Development, I do need the Code complete feature, since it becomes difficult. For this I have to Switch to Eclipse or Sublime.

I also know that `Ctrl+Space` triggers the code complete window in BlueJ.

Is there any way that this gets triggered as soon as we hit the '.' after any object?
Or any extensions which may make my job easier rather than hitting `Ctrl+Space`every time?

Answer (score 4):

I'm in the same boat as you for having a love for BlueJ, however the IDE was mainly created for [teaching object-oriented programming](https://www.bluej.org/about.html) rather than actual development (although I've done a fair bit of development in it myself).

I too have looked around for a code-completion plugin, although that kind of goes against the teaching aspect as Richard H mentions in [his post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161114181928/http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.help/2005-08/msg00699.html) on the subject.

So to answer the question, unfortunately there is no way to implement auto-complete unless someone chooses to develop an extension in the future. Although I doubt it will be endorsed by the BlueJ team.